# getting dquote> prompt when trying to execute the following Linux command in a MacBook Pro Terminal

Tags: linux

Trying to execute the following command on a MacBook Pro Terminal:

find /users/dougrobson/Documents -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "????22*” -exec cp {} /users/dougrobson/Documents/year22/;

I ran it once with different name search terms:  "????21+" instead of "????22*" and
with different directory to write to year21 instead of year22.

With just those changes made, I now get dquote> instead of a completion.

looked for syntax errors.  I see only one use of double quotes, and they are paired.

Comment: fyi this is off-topic here. Probably better to ask on either [unix.se] or [apple.se]